# What will be equivalent PerfMon counters for SQL Response Time?

Tags: sql-server, performance-testing, perfmon

What will be equivalent PerfMon counters for SQL Response Time?
Please check image for more clarification.

I have posted the counter from Resource Monitor. I want equivalent PerfMon counters for **SQL Response Time** (last coulmn) to show in Grafana.

[image: Resource Monitor]

Comment: I don't think there is a PMON counter with this information. An average time for all queries wouldn't be particularly useful as each query is unique. That said, you could get the average time for all cached queries using the DMVs: `SELECT SUM(qs.total_elapsed_time) / SUM(qs.execution_count) AS AvgResponseTimeMicroseconds FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS qs;`.

Comment: Thanks..is there any way to get separate response time for each file as shown in Resource Monitor?

Comment: I added a query to get the information by file from SQL Server's perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DMV query below will report the IO stats for each file since the SQL instances was last started, with the average total, read, and write response times calculated.

```
WITH io_stats AS (
    SELECT
          mf.physical_name
        , vfs.NumberReads + vfs.NumberWrites AS NumberTotal
        , vfs.IoStallReadMS + vfs.IoStallWriteMS AS IoStallTotalMS
        , vfs.NumberReads
        , vfs.IoStallReadMS
        , vfs.NumberWrites
        , vfs.IoStallWriteMS
    FROM sys.master_files AS mf
    CROSS APPLY sys.fn_virtualfilestats(database_id, file_id) AS vfs
)
SELECT
      physical_name
    , NumberTotal
    , IoStallTotalMS
    , IoStallTotalMS / CASE WHEN NumberTotal = 0 THEN NULL ELSE NumberTotal END AS ResponseTime
    , NumberReads
    , IoStallReadMS
    , IoStallReadMS / CASE WHEN NumberReads = 0 THEN NULL ELSE NumberReads END AS ResponseTimeRead
    , NumberWrites
    , IoStallWriteMS
    , IoStallWriteMS / CASE WHEN NumberWrites = 0 THEN NULL ELSE NumberWrites END AS ResponseTimeWrite
FROM io_stats;
```

Comment: This query is giving me error. Should I change some values OR execute it as it is? Thanks you.

Comment: The query works for me. What error are you getting? If there are other statements in the batch before this query, make sure the last statement is [terminated with a semi-colon](https://www.dbdelta.com/always-use-semicolon-statement-terminators/).

Comment: the query works on my AWS database but on my working office DB does not work. https://imgur.com/a/G9CvhpO

Comment: If i comment those two error lines on my part the query works just fine...

Comment: What does `SELECT @@VERSION;` return for your on-prem SQL instance? I tested only with currently supported SQL Server versions (SQL 2012 and later).

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/3bQ5pTQ
this is same on AWS and office db. But the query works on AWS and does not work on office db.

Comment: @adj009, I suspect the collation of your office database is case-sensitive. I changed the column names in my answer to a consistent case. Please try the revised query.